# Linq to XML: get default namespace of rss

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I call the methods within several classes this way:

```
GetResult(XElement item, XNamespace ns) {
    item.Element(ns + "title").Value;
}
```

In order to initialize the feeds and to access the elements as stated above I want to find out the default namespace. Without any namespace declaration it works fine (item.Element("title").Value) and the value of the element is returned.

So how can I find out the correct namespace? The result of the method root.GetDefaultNamespace() is empty somehow...

```
<rss xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" version="2.0">
    <channel>...</channel>
</rss>
```

//edit

Ok, my code so far:

```
    XDocument thisFeed = XDocument.Load(@"http://www.spiegel.de/schlagzeilen/tops/index.rss");
    XElement root = thisFeed.Root;
    XNamespace ns = root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("content");
    //result:
    Console.WriteLine("DefaultNamespace: " + root.GetDefaultNamespace());
    //result: http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/
    Console.WriteLine("GetNamespaceOfPrefix('content'): " + ns);
    //works
    Console.WriteLine("Result: " + root.Element("channel").Element("title").Value);
    //Doesn't work
    Console.WriteLine("Result: " + root.Element(ns + "channel").Element(ns + "title").Value);
```

Comment: Seems to be something "wrong" with your rss as indeed there is no default namespace specified, only a "content" namespace. Maybe you need to hardcode it?

Comment: May be not exactly what you're asking for, but have you tried SyndicationFeed class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx)? I found it very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("content");
```

`content` in your sample is *prefix*. Nice explanation of namespaces and prefixes can be found at this **[w3schools article](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp)**

**UPDATE:**

There is no default namespace defined in that document, there is only namespace for elements with prefix, other elements are retrieved without namespace. I found only element `<content:encoded>` to be using prefix, for that element you need to use `ns`.

Comment: You're welcome. I tested it using the sample that you posted, `GetNamespaceOfPrefix` method returned 'http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/' as a namespace. What are you getting when you run this? (Not the `GetDefaultNamespace` - that would return namespace if it was defined like `xmlns="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"`). Is `rss` element really the root?

Comment: For testing I used this feed: http://www.spiegel.de/schlagzeilen/tops/index.rss Please see my first post for further details. It seems odd that the default namespace is empty...

Comment: If there was a default namespace defined it would implicitly apply to all elements. Since there is prefix in the declaration, that namespace only applies to prefixed elements.