# I can't display the result of my rss reader

Tags: c#, xaml, rss

I have the following problem :

this is my xaml code:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Name="ResultsView">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <StackPanel Width="340">
                                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Author}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Published}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Guid}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Link}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

and this my code for binding the listbox:

```
private void Feed(object Sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            XElement _xml;
            try
            {
                if (!e.Cancelled)
                {
                    _xml = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
                    ResultsView.Items.Clear();
                    foreach (XElement value in _xml.Elements("channel").Elements("item"))
                    {
                        Tweet _item = new Tweet();
                        _item.Title = value.Element("title").Value;
                        _item.Author = value.Element("author").Value;
                        _item.Published = DateTime.Parse(value.Element("pubDate").Value);
                        _item.Guid = value.Element("guid").Value;
                        _item.Link = value.Element("link").Value;
                        _item.Description = Regex.Replace(value.Element("description").Value,
                        @"<(.|\n)*?>", String.Empty);

                        ResultsView.Items.Add(_item);
                        MessageBox.Show("test");     
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // Ignore Errors
            }
        }
```

the code when i launch the binding:

```
private void Lookup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WebClient _client = new WebClient();
            _client.DownloadStringCompleted += Feed;
            _client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri((_value + Location.Text)));
        }
```

and this is the rss feed : [rss feed link](http://bit.ly/1b2I5BK)

here is indeed a valid rss feed but I never add an item to my listbox. (the alert is never displayed) and I can not find out why. Someone would have an idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `ResultsView.Items` an `ObservableCollection`? You can also remove `try catch` and enable exceptions to see if you get any errors

Comment: The empty `catch {}` is very good at hiding the root problem. Try without for a change.

Comment: it's indeed a bad idea because the problem is in fact the format of the datetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is that you ignore XML namespaces in the feed.

It should look something like:

```
XNameSpace ns = ...;
foreach (XElement value in _xml.Elements( ns + "channel").Elements(ns + "item"))
...
```

See [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14957265/60761) for some RSS related examples.

After that, I'm not so sure that a DataTemplate is applied to `Items`. Customary is to bind through the `ItemsSource` property.

And don't use `_` on local variables names. They are only to be used like that on private fields.

Comment: with this rss feed : http://cespage.com/silverlight/tutorials.xml it works fine ... so i think it's a problem with the rss feed right ?